# как залогинится в wp с помощью x-www-browser

Tags: linux, wordpress, bash, webbrowser

```
open_site_wp="https://${HOST}/wp-admin?log=${log}&pwd=${pwd}"

x-www-browser  --new-window  ${open_site_wp}
```

возможно ли открыть сайт с помощью  `x-www-browser` в терменале

и сразу зайти в админку передав логин и пароль ,
вот только вопрос как их передать ?

Comment: Так как ты написал - нет. См: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

Размещаешь на сайте страничку на php, которая принимает GET запрос и создаст форму с логином, паролем ( можно).

Добавь яваскрипт на onload, который эту форму засабмитит.

Получишь новую сессионную куку и можно делать редирект в админку.

Comment: Так а как куки попадут именно в браузер ?

Comment: самодельную страницу ты открываешь в браузере и получаешь яваскрипт который сделает пост с логином-паролем. самодельная страница должна лежать на сайте